# How can you best train your labrum?

Tags: strength-training, training, injury, injury-prevention, shoulders

I've torn my labrum twice. Same labrum both times, right shoulder. Also- both doing the same exercise, Military Press (or shoulder press). The injuries were 10 years apart. One required surgery and the other that I not use is for 6+ weeks.

My question is, are there any low impact training techniques to help prevent future injury?

I still want to train those muscles, but I am very nervous. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How much weight / volume do you usually press? How did you torn your labrum, the same way both times?

Comment: 10 years ago, it was with 100lbs on a straight bar after months of using 90lbs, I decided to move up weight. A few months ago it was a 30lb dumbbell that did it. It was the same motion both times.